# Schematic editor is 404

Tags: bug

Trying to edit the schematic in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/107091/17608), I get redirected to circuitlab, see some dialogs flash too quickly to read, then [land at a 404 resource](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/plugins/schematics/editor?edit=https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ykUT.png).

Comment: Just tried to repeat this and got the same.

Comment: Perhaps it's relevant that the question was migrated.

Comment: Looks like it is, following actually works if you want to try and edit it: http://ham.stackexchange.com/plugins/schematics/editor?edit=http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ykUT.png

Comment: @PeterJ that gets me to the editor, but it can't be saved. Clicking the save button does a progress indicator like it's being saved, but then it stops and I'm left still at the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Update: **Based on the time stamps, @PhilFrost answered/created the schematic *while the question was on Ham, before it migrated over*. I created one on that question, and it works fine.**

I tried copying the schematic code, like I normally do to ""edit"" and work on someone else's schematic, since editing is really just creates a new schematic. And it won't work.
It keeps giving (It actually says electronics.stackexchange.com, more on that in a minute):
[image]

Since the ham se beta has access to the circuit lab as well, it might be a backend issue where the circuit button sends a different return url or the image address is associated with ham and not EE?

[image: schematic]

I copied and pasted the code to a new question in ham and then edited it there. It worked fine.

[image: schematic]

**But on the same note, a EE schematic copied to ham and clicking on edit, will not work either. It's a cross-site/domain policy error. For XSS reasons no doubt. Or noone foresaw the Circuitlab tool being used outside of EE?**